# Is it a good way to use an auto increment integer field as the primary key?

Tags: database-design, auto-increment

In database design, is it a good way to use an auto-increment integer field as the primary key?

For Example, I have a `tenant` table, `tenant_id` is unique. In this case, do I need a auto_increment key?

What the benefits of the `auto_increment primary key` and when to use it?

Thank you.